# PHP why doesn't this code echo?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, echo

After executing the following code, `$i` doesn't echo if I have the `$q3` delete query enabled. If I comment it or delete `$q3`, then everything is fine.

How can I get this to work?

```
$isfound = in_array("empty",$currentrooms0);
if($isfound===true){
    for($i=0; $i<count($currentrooms0);$i++){
        if($currentrooms0[$i]=="empty"){
            $q3=mysqli_query($conn0,"delete from room_attributes where _current_created_rooms='empty' order by id desc limit 1")or die(mysqli_error($conn0));    
            echo $i-1;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your query failing and outputting an error by any chance?

Comment: have you got display_errors enabled?

Comment: Check the `{` and `}`s in your code.

Comment: I think there is an error on you query. Run that query separately on database to know the error. For that reason it is execute the die statement.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it won't echo is because there is an error in your SQL and `mysqli_query` returns false in such case.

The SQL causes an error because you cannot use `ORDER BY` inside a `WHERE` clause that directly belongs to a `DELETE`

If what you are looking to delete the topmost attribute then you might want to consider using this sql and your code should work.

```
DELETE FROM room_attributes
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM room_attributes
  WHERE _current_created_rooms='empty'
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: here is the answer                                             [code]$isfound = in_array("empty",$currentrooms0);
if($isfound===true){
    for($i=0; $i<count($currentrooms0);$i++){
        if($currentrooms0[$i]=="empty"){
            $q3=mysqli_query($conn0,"delete from room_attributes where _current_created_rooms='empty' order by id desc limit 1")or die(mysqli_error($conn0));    
           if(i>$i-1) {echo 0;}else{echo $i-1;}
            break;
        }
    }[/code]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with mysqli_connect please try to do following ..

```
if($q3 ===TRUE){
    echo $i-1;
    break;
}else{
    echo "Connection Problem";
}
```

Comment: $isfound = in_array("empty",$currentrooms0);
if($isfound===true){
    for($i=0; $i<count($currentrooms0);$i++){
        if($currentrooms0[$i]=="empty"){
            $q3=mysqli_query($conn0,"delete from room_attributes where _current_created_rooms='empty' order by id desc limit 1")or die(mysqli_error($conn0));    
            echo $i-1;
            break;
        }
    }

Answer (score -2):

The OP wrote:

> here is the answer:
>
> ```
> $isfound = in_array("empty",$currentrooms0); 
> if($isfound===true){ 
>     for($i=0; $i<count($currentrooms0);$i++){ 
>         if($currentrooms0[$i]=="empty"){ 
>             $q3=mysqli_query($conn0,"delete from room_attributes where _current_created_rooms='empty' order by id desc limit 1") or die(mysqli_error($conn0)); 
>             if(i>$i-1) {echo 0;}else{echo $i-1;} 
>             break; 
>          } 
>     }
> ```

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)